# Question about quadratic form

Tags: matrices, quadratic-forms

> Suppose that $\mathbf{x}^{\prime}=(x, y, z)$ and $$\mathbf{A}=\left(\begin{array}{lll}
> a & d & e \\
> d & b & f \\
> e & f & c
> \end{array}\right)$$ Then find $\mathbf{x}^{\prime} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$, which is called a "quadratic form."

---

*What I have tried, but I am doubtful about its accuracy:*
The equation $\mathbf{x}^{\prime} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$ is a type of quadratic equation where the variables are represented by matrices and the coefficients are derived from a given matrix $\mathbf{A}$. In order to find $\mathbf{x}^{\prime} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$ in this case, we must first calculate $\mathbf{A}^{\prime}$. After we have the value of $\mathbf{A}^{\prime}$, we can calculate $\mathbf{x}^{\prime} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$ by $\mathbf{x}^{\prime} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x} \mathbf{A}^{\prime}$.

Proof: We can do this because they are both equal to the trace of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$. The trace of any matrix is the sum of the elements in the main diagonal. As such, $\mathbf{x}^{\prime} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}$ is equal to the sum of the elements in the main diagonal of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$, and $\mathbf{x} \mathbf{A}^{\prime}$ is equal to the same sum. Consequently, $\mathbf{x}^{\prime} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x} \mathbf{A}^{\prime}$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think they just want you to write down the result of the matrix calculation $$\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&d&e\\d&b&f\\e&f&c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$ in terms of $x, y, z$ - which is a $1\times 1$ matrix i.e. a _number_, essentially.

Comment: Equation????????

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{x}^{\prime}$ is a $1 \times 3$ matrix; $\mathbf{x}$ is a $3 \times 1$ matrix. Multiply the matrices $\mathbf{x}^{\prime}A\mathbf{x}$. Your answer is the $1 \times 1$matrix whose only element is $$ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2dxy+2exz+2fyz$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use trace to obtain this result.
$$
s=
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}
=
\mathrm{tr}
\left( 
\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}
\right)
=
\mathrm{tr}
\left( 
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T
\right)
=
\mathbf{A} : \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T
$$
where we use the colon operator : to denote the Frobenius inner product and the symmetry of $\mathbf{A}$.

Using your notations
$$
s=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & d & e \\
d & b & f \\
e & f & c
\end{pmatrix}
:
\begin{pmatrix}
x^2 & xy & xz \\
yx & y^2 & yz \\
zx & zy & z^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since
$\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{B}
= \sum_{ij} A_{ij}B_{ij}
$, the final result is easily found